# How to Properly Use AngularJS ng-style with Calc

Tags: angularjs

I apologize for the poorly worded title. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
ng-style="{'min-height': 'calc(100% - '+footerHeight+')'}"
```

I'm trying to set the min-height equal to 100% - the footerHeight but the code above isn't working - anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is footerheight a string that includes pixels? If not you'll need to add that as well. In general, it looks right. Have you looked at what the `style` tag on the element has for a min-height after it runs?

Comment: yes, it doesn't generate

Comment: I changed it to ng-style="{'min-height': 'calc(100% - '+footerHeight+'px)'}" and it worked. (added px)